# Spark textarea with different slider

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, flex4, scrollbar, flex-spark

I am rather new to Flex and have a problem with a scrollbar for a textarea. Basically, I would want the textarea to have a vertical scrollbar that looks like the VSlider component, not like a VSrollBar. (I.e. a line with a dot tracker, not a box with a box tracker).

Now I figured out how I could make a textarea with no scrollbars and link it to a seperate VSlider component and update via events, but I am pretty sure there should be some way to use only the textarea and set its scrollbar component to look like the VSlider instead of the VScrollBar.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, I ended up using a VSlider, which I "manually" synced with the textarea scrolling via event listenered. Not the most smooth way, but easiest to implement in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using spark TextArea and a skin for Vertical Scroll Bar.
Also you have to skin each button from this skin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
             xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009">
    <fx:Metadata>
        <![CDATA[ 
            [HostComponent("spark.components.VScrollBar")]
        ]]>
    </fx:Metadata> 
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="inactive" />
    </s:states>
    <s:Group top="2" horizontalCenter="0" bottom="2" left="2" right="2">
        <s:Button id="track" top="8" bottom="8" width="10" focusEnabled="false" 
                  skinClass="skins.scroller.VerticalScrollBarTrackSkin"/>
        <s:Button id="thumb" horizontalCenter="0" focusEnabled="false" visible.inactive="false"
                  skinClass="skins.scroller.VerticalScrollBarThumbSkin" buttonMode="true"/>
        <s:Button id="decrementButton" top="0" enabled.inactive="false"
                  focusEnabled="false" horizontalCenter="0" buttonMode="true"
                  skinClass="skins.scroller.VerticalScrollBarDecrementButtonSkin"/>
        <s:Button id="incrementButton" bottom="0" enabled.inactive="false"
                  focusEnabled="false" horizontalCenter="0" buttonMode="true"
                  skinClass="skins.scroller.VerticalScrollBarIncrementButtonSkin"/>
    </s:Group>
</s:SparkSkin>
```

Then you have to apply style to your application.

```
s|VScrollBar
{
    skinClass:ClassReference("skins.scroller.VerticalScrollBarSkin");
}
```